gcc bug? name-hiding vs. specialization for class template with same name in derived class, but only when base class is also template

Is the error message shown below a gcc 13.1.0 bug?  This code compiles fine under clang 18.0.2 and MSVC 19.41.  This code even compiles OK on gcc if you change s0 into a non-template class.  There is something specific about s0 being a template class that makes gcc upset.
The goal is that the derived class s1 should have its own class template foo that completely hides any foo from s0.  And then after declaring foo, s1 also wants to specify that s1::foo<T> is a friend of s1.  It seems like gcc is interpreting the first line of s1 as a partial specialization of s0<int>::foo<T>, but again (oddly) only if s0 is a template class.
template< class X >
struct s0
{
    template< class T >
    struct foo;
};
struct s1 : public s0<int>
{
    // - this should be an entirely new class template "foo"
    // - hiding the "foo" in s0<int>
    // [basic.scope.hiding]
    //
    template< class T >
    struct foo;

    // - gcc error is:
    // partial specialization 's0<int>::foo<T>' declared 'friend'
    // (gcc thinks the line above is a partial specialization??)
    //
    template< class T >
    friend
    struct foo;
};

If it's a bug, any ideas for a workaround?

With template< class T > friend struct s1::foo; gcc passes, but no longer msvc Demo

Nested classes are implicitly friend, so you might remove the friend completlyDemo.

Such question was asked recently in this month. The answer: gcc is right. The name scope of the template< class T > friend struct foo is the scope outside of struct s1 and there is no template< class T > struct foo defined. Follow the above comment and remove friend.

@3CxEZiVlQ Aha, removing the friend entirely is great; didn't realize it was already friend.   Out of curiosity, do you have a link to the recent Q?  Even though the friend line cannot see earlier in s1, still curious why gcc thinks there is a partial specialization of s0<int>::foo<T> going on...wouldn't a partial specialization require different template parameters?  Thanks.

@3CxEZiVlQ The error message makes no sense though.

@LouisSemprini I don't have the question, but the standard reference is here.

@user17732522 perhaps it has something to do with the similar (but not identical) issue described here or even the fixed gcc bug described in the other answers.

@user17732522 or perhaps when gcc confusingly refers to specialization, gcc is referring to specialization of s0 as a whole (nothing to do with foo specifically; would apply to any s0 member, even one without a duplicate name in s1) and gcc is thinking I want s1 to befriend only a hypothetical s0<int> specialization of the s0 class template.  Indeed, if we remove the first line of s1 (remove the derived foo) gcc still gives the error.  Even if so, s0<int> seems like a full specialization, not partial, hmm.

@LouisSemprini I don't think it is really possible to explain why GCC produces that error message without looking at the code. I doubt that there is a developer intent here. It looks like a bug to me that this specific error message is produced. But as mentioned above, it should still fail with a clearer error message.

Ok, thanks to @Jarod42 and @3CxEZiVlQ and @user17732522 we've got as much of an answer as we'll get without looking at gcc source:

First of all, the friend is unnecessary because nested classes are already implicitly friends of their containing class. Yay!  Deletion is always the best solution.
But for those like me still curious about the mysterious error message, the insights are:

the scope in which the name in the friend declaration is looked up is not s1 class scope but rather "the innermost enclosing namespace scope" (dcl.meaning.general.2.3).  So the friend declaration on the second line of s1 will "look right past" any declaration of a new symbol foo in s1.  In fact if you remove the first line of s1, the error persists.
the spec wording "the innermost enclosing namespace scope" suggests that gcc should look for foo in the global scope, where there is no foo, but in fact from the compiler error message we can see that gcc thinks we are trying to friend the specialization s0<int>::foo<T> so gcc is clearly looking in s0.  Not sure if this is correct or not, but there is a non-normative note in basic.lookup.unqual saying "When a class scope is searched, the scopes of its base classes are also searched ([class.member.lookup]).
If it inherits from a single base, it is as if the scope of the base immediately contains the scope of the derived class," which could justify gcc's choice (but is not normative).  Is there a normative version of this in the spec that clarifies it?
really no idea why gcc complains about a specialization at all (since a friend declaration does not declare any specialization, as mentioned in this related, fixed gcc bug about injected-class-name).  Perhaps it might just be a buggy diagnostic, possibly relating to a tricky (mis)interpretation of the name foo as s0<int>::foo<T> and treating that as a specialization in a similar (but not identical) way seen in this answer.



